# Inheriting the auto-generated python file into Multiple Classes in PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a pyuic generated file for a tool that i'm writing and I'm trying to organise the code better by dividing it into multiple classes ( five to be precise ). The problem is that while `self.pushButton_Refresh` is accessible from the Main Class, it isn't accessible in the UART class inspite of inheriting the Main Class. What exactly am i doing wrong?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from UI.Main import Ui_MainWindow

class Main(Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self,dialog):
                Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
                self.setupUi(dialog)
                uart=UART()



class UART(Main):
        def __init__(self):
                self.pushButton_Refresh.clicked.connect(self.getport)

        def getport(self):
                print("[*] UART_getport invoked ")
```

Comment: Use `super`, or call the base-class `__init__`.

Comment: @ekhumoro, UART is the base class and i do have an init function  __init__ right?

Comment: No, `Main` is the base-class of `UART`, just as `Ui_MainWindow` is the base-class of `Main`. In the `__init__` of `Main`, you have called the `__init__` of its base-class, but in `UART`, you haven't. That is what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @ekhumoro. Thanks for the help! Its working now!